# Please help me understand this JUnit exam question

Tags: java, testing, junit

When studying for my upcoming exam I stumbled upon this question about JUnit in an old exam and I don't really get the point of it.

Given were the following pictures and the questions:

Class one:

[image: Class one]

Class two:

[image: Class two]

1. Explain which problem exists when testing 'Class A'
2. Develop a solution for the problem
3. Write a JUnit test to show if 'Method s' displays the String correctly.

Is it an error in the actual code logic or more with the interface not being implemented correctly?

Comment: I assume the problem they are getting at is that the class instantiates unrelated classes of its own (the LinkedList). It is not possible to unit test "A" without also testing unrelated code. I assume they want the reader to offer dependency injection as a solution to this.

Comment: Can you please post code as code and not as pictures? That would really improve readability

Comment: I actually don't see a problem here. If you know what values will be returned for the calls to b, then the you know fully the return value of calling s(b). The goal of a test is to test the public API, in this case the method "s". Tests should not be dependent on the implementation details.

Comment: Method `s` doesn't display anything so that's another point in the list of issues with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at these two images you attached for a while now but I'm really confused.

When I write tests I need to know what the purpose of the method or class is but we have very little information about the desired functionality in the presented code.

Your question: "Is it an error in the actual code logic" is very hard to answer because you would have to try and decipher the meaning of the code, which lacks any form of variable names or class names. Neither are there any comments describing anything. On top of this there is an interface with unspecified logic

```
public boolean u(int v, int w)
```

What this is supposed to be one can only wonder.

This means we lack the most vital part: **an understanding of the intended behavior of the code we need to test**.

It wouldn't be much of a test if we only parse the code and write a test that only adheres to the specified operations in the function. It's kind of the reverse of Test Driven Development, writing tests that work for the code, rather than writing tests that specify how the code is intended to work, and then modify the code to work as asserted by the test.

If that question came up on my exam I would refuse to write any code or attempt to test it. I would simply specify that the information provided is not sufficient to provide a meaningful test.

I hope this answer was somewhat useful to you. I believe it would be interesting to see what your professor has to say about this question. It might be the case that they want the student to realize what a unit test really is and does not expect you to actually write any code, but to come to the conclusion that the code indeed makes no sense to test.

Answer (score 0):

The principal problem of the Class A is that the names of class, variables and method dont says nothing. Isnt easy to recognize any business rules in this class.

In the interface B the same problem occurs, with addiction of the comment "COmplex funcionality" that dont says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A method of class A makes use of the method t() which is defined in interface A. To solve this, class A has to implement interface B and explicitly implement the method t() in the body of the class.
   public class A implements B{
    .....
    public int t(){
    return ...;
    }
   }